# How to stream video from ubuntu to XBMC?

Tags: video-streaming, ubuntu-12.10, xbmc

Does anyone know how to stream video from ubuntu 12.10 to XBMC media center (running on raspberry pi). I know I can enable the AirPlay on the XBMC, but couldn't figure how to stream the video from ubuntu. I've tried to AirPlay plugin for Totem, but it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, I've found a partial solution:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/instantly-send-youtube-video-tv-xbmc/

Comment: Just an FYI, what you want to do, probably, is stream to a "UPNP render".  It sounds like "rygel" does this, but I haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this successfully with my Ubuntu Studio 12.10 workstation and tablets/laptops running XBMC on Linux or Android.

You will need either:
1) a DLNA-compatible content server (such as PLEX) running on your Ubuntu workstation/server to feed your Raspberry PI XBMC client ; or
2) an SMB (Samba) share on your Ubuntu system that your XMBC client on the Raspberry PI can scan for compatible media.

Of the two, I recommend the Plex option.

You can also check out this integration of Plex and XBMC here: [Plex Add-on for XBMC](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Add-on%3aPleXBMC)

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but as I understand it, you will have to initiate playback from the Pi running XBMC. You will not be able to initiate the playback directly from the Ubuntu machine to the Pi.